# Apache SSL server not starting, "Address already in use"?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have installed Apache 2.0.58 together with PHP 5.1.4. When I start the server using `./apachectl start`, I manage to get the server running to serve HTTP as well as PHP pages, but when I try to start SSL for HTTPS using `./apachectl startssl`, I get the error below:

```
(125)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:54912
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

When I run `netstat -an | grep 54912` I don't see that port 54912 is being used at all. For reference, I hosted my HTTPS page on port 54912, and while in "httpd.conf" it already has the `Listen 54912` directive, I also changed the file "ssl.conf" to `Listen 54912` from the default `Listen 443`for https.

Any idea how I can get my server to run and serve HTTPS?

Comment: If you have two Listen 54912 directives, one of them will fail. Don't.

Comment: in that case, which one should i change? and the one i don't want, should i just change it to the default port 443 for ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the server running! :)
As mentioned by @EJP, the problem is because there are 2 **Listen 54912** inside config. So by changing the file **httpd.conf** to **Listen 14912** and retaining the file **ssl.conf** to **Listen 54912**, I can now run **apachectl startssl** and after entering the password, the server is up and running!
Special thanks to Tim Yencken for the help. (Dunno if he's here or not).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `apachectl startssl` was deprecated in [version 2.0](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/apachectl.html) (and was removed in has [version 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html))

It's likely that `apache start` has already started the SSL virtual hosts, in particular if these virtual hosts (or other SSL-related options) haven't been defined in a `<IfDefine SSL>` section (because in Apache 2.0, `apachectl startssl` is equivalent to `apachectl -k start -DSSL`): they would be part of the main configuration.

Comment: hmmm, but when i just use **./apachectl start** instead of **./apachectl startssl**, the page is served on the normal **http**, not **https**. i'll try the equivalent command **./apachectl -k start -DSSL** and see if it works. been stuck here for days, heh...

Comment: Perhaps you could post a bit more config (even though SO isn't really the right place for this, as this isn't a programming question).

Comment: you mean the ssl.conf and the httpd.conf files? sorry i'm totally new at this.

Comment: running the **./apachectl -k start -DSSL** command also produce the same error message.